# How to upload large files using SAPUI5 FileUploader

Tags: javascript, xml, file-upload, sapui5, sap-gateway

I am using the `FileUploader` in SAP WEB IDE to upload text files to SAP back end database through OData Services.

I am able to upload small files with size around 10-20 KB but my requirement is to be able to upload files with size 100-150 MB.

Code for `FileUploader` in controller:

```js
var oFileUploader = this.getView().byId("fileUploader1");

oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
    name: "slug",
    value: oFileUploader.getValue()
}));
    
oFileUploader.addHeaderParameter(new sap.ui.unified.FileUploaderParameter({
    name: "x-csrf-token",
    value: data
}));
    
oFileUploader.setSendXHR(true);
oFileUploader.setUploadUrl(serviceUrl);
oFileUploader.upload();

alert("Upload Successful");
```

Code for XML View:

```xml
<Page title="{i18n>appDescription}" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
    <u:FileUploader
        id="fileUploader1"
        name="myFileUpload"
        uploadUrl=""
        uploadOnChange="false"
        width="400px"
        tooltip="Upload your file to the local server"
        uploadComplete="handleUploadComplete" />
    <Button
        text="Upload File"
        press="handleUploadPress" />
</Page>
```

For some time I see the status as pending and then `failed: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` in the Network tab of browser console.

Note: I am able to upload same 101 MB text file into SAP back end system directly.

Comment: are you using netweaver gateway to connect to backend? if yes, check https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/48/ad5afa8bc96744e10000000a421937/content.htm

Comment: @SunilBN I am using OData Services to connect to Netweaver Gateway from SAP webide.

Comment: Netweaver Gateway will have timeout setting for calls.. so check the timeout parameters as mentioned in the above link..

Comment: Did you try from gateway client? if that works, then I am sure its some settings in Gateway system.. http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73ehp1/helpdata/en/48/ad76299eff35b7e10000000a42189d/content.htm

Comment: I have tried directly uploading the file into gateway, initially it was also not taking the file but later when we increased the memory for it, then it was successfully uploading the TEXT file. I'll check for timeout settings and update.

Comment: @SunilBN I am able to upload files upto 100MB but not beyond that. I have asked the BASIS team to look into link you have mentioned. They have made some changes but still not able to upload bigger files, so i have found a workaround by zipping the file and sending.

Comment: @MatthiasGünter No i couldn't solved the problem, but found two solutions, first compress the files, it reduces the size to a great extent. Second we split the file into smaller files then uploaded using macro written in excel. I used the first solution to compress and upload.

Answer (score 0):

There is a default limitation of 102400 KB on the HTTP server-side.

The limitation can be checked and changed through SMICM > go to Parameters.

Check the SAP official document before some changes :
https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_NETWEAVER_731/0c333adb55cd4dbf8e92a5175703224c/483e87b3ca6b72d0e10000000a42189c.html?locale=en-US&version=7.31.25